How can I customize the scroll and snap anmiations in react native when use FlatList
The width of each item included by the flatlist is equal to screen width. When I swipe left or right, I don't like the automatic snap animation effect. Specifically, the animation duration is too short and there is a stuttering feeling.
I have tried using built-in flatlist components such as "decelerationRate" and "snapToInterval", but none of them have the desired effect.
I have also tried the Reanimated library, but I have been searching for documentation for a long time and have not found a way to implement custom animations.
Whether it's Reanimated flatlist or the built-in flatlist's scrollTo method, the animation parameters only have options such as "{animated: true}" to switch animations, and there is no way to adjust the duration.
If you could help me, I would be very grateful. I have been looking for a solution for several days now.

If you don't have any margin/paddings and every item on your <FlatList /> is the same width, you only need to pass pagingEnabled, decelerationRate="fast", and snapToInterval. But if you have different item width you may want to use snapToOffsets (and even getItemLayout).
Look at this example on Snack.
In any case, here's the source code if you want to look at it quickly.
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, View, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const itemWidth = 300;
const itemHeight = 400;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
const marginHorizontal = (screenWidth - itemWidth) / 2;

const colors = ['blue', 'brown', 'pink', 'purple'];

export default function App() {
  const renderItem = React.useCallback(
    ({ item, index }: ListRenderItemInfo<RGBColor>) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            height: itemHeight,
            width: itemWidth,
            backgroundColor: item,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        />
      );
    },
    []
  );
  const keyExtractor = React.useCallback(
    (data, index) => `${index}-${data}`,
    []
  );
  /** In case you want more granular control over the item width */
  const getItemLayout = React.useCallback(
    (_, index) => ({
      index,
      length: itemWidth,
      offset: itemWidth * index + marginHorizontal,
    }),
    []
  );
  const snapToOffsets = React.useMemo(
    () => colors.map((_, index) => itemWidth * (index + 1)),
    []
  );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
        height: itemHeight,
      }}>
      <Animated.FlatList
        style={{ marginVertical: 20, height: itemHeight }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          alignItem: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: marginHorizontal,
        }}
        pagingEnabled
        snapToOffsets={snapToOffsets}
        decelerationRate="fast"
        snapToInterval
        snapToAlignment="center"
        horizontal
        data={colors}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        // getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          start: 0,
          end: 0,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
        pointerEvents="none">
        <SafeAreaView
          style={{
            marginVertical: 20,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
            height: itemHeight,
            width: itemWidth,
            flex: 1,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}



I have tried this situation before, but neither decelerationRate="fast" nordecelerationRate="Normal" is the effect I want, even if give it a number. They will still move to the next item very quickly. I want it to be like a non-linear acceleration or spring

You can play with decelerationRate, it accepts 'normal', 'fast', and any number between 0 and 1, where 'normal' is 0.998 on iOS and 0.985 on Android (this is the default value), and 'fast' is 0.99 on iOS and 0.9 on Android.

But if the user don't necessarily need to swipe on the <FlatList />, then you can use Animated.Value() or Reanimated to do the animation you want.
